# iOS UIButton in UITableView Header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I have a subview that acts as a container view in a table header.  In that, I have a UIButton.  The button is not receiving any touch events.  (Yes everything is wired up properly in IB...)

So my question is, is it a common problem to have buttons not receiving any events in the header?  Do I need to forward any events?

I can't really post any code, since it would appear to be more of an IB problem.  Anyone experience this before?

---

UPDATE:  If I put the button in the footer, with no container view, it will work.  So perhaps it's because it is in a view inside the header??

Comment: Do you mean the button does not appear to be touchable (doesn't change appearance when tapped) or that its action never fires?

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening...

Comment: After rereading that comment, it's both.  It's not changing when you tap it, and the event never fires...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, I feel like a moron.  I didn't have user interaction enabled.  Sorry for wasting all your time guys...

Comment: It's all good. Just be sure to check this answer as correct when the system allows for it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :) Gotta be careful with that setting

Comment: WHERE did you have to set that? A location or some sort of reference would have been extraordinarily helpful.

Comment: This was four years ago.  I don't have a clue anymore.  Sorry about that.  I honestly don't even remember what this is.

Answer (score 0):

I've included UIButtons and even UITableViews in my table header before, so I don't think it should be an issue. Something is just not setup correctly. I didn't have to do anything special to get touch events to fire.

Comment: The thing is, it's not just a button.  It is an entire view with an image, labels, and the button.  I am not sure if how those objects are interacting is influencing it?